# i want to take print of a html page which i m sending the url of the file and need to take the print out without QPrintDialog

Tags: c++, qt

Is there any other way instead of using QPrintDialog box to print i dont want to show dialog box in qt

```
QWebEngineView view;
view.setUrl(QUrl(html));

QWebEnginePage *webpage = view.page();
QPrinter printer(QPrinter::HighResolution);

QPrintDialog dialog(&printer, webpage->view());
if (dialog.exec() != QDialog::Accepted)
    return;
```

Comment: What's wrong with [`void QWebEnginePage::print(QPrinter *printer, const QWebEngineCallback<bool> &resultCallback)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginepage.html#print)?

Comment: i want to  print a web page whoose url i m passing from the qml side and i need to take a print of it can u help me with that

Comment: Yes, but for starters, you should revise your question to include all relevant data.

Comment: i am new to Qt creator so can any one send me how to take the input as url of any page and print it without the QPrintDialog box